# change date from y-m-d to m/d/y format in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert this `2008-01-01` to `1/1/2008` in R. I've tried `as.Date(abc,'%m/%d/%y')` but it doesn't work...instead I get a bunch of NAs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Downvote for no research effort. Pasting your exact question title into the 'ask question' title box lists the duplicate under 'questions that may already have your answer'

Comment: My question was a little different actually...and these solutions are also much quicker than those listed previously.

I searched for an hour on this.

Comment: You searched for an hour? The first page of Google results for 'R change date format' gives the same answers as below, along with several other R-bloggers articles and tutorials covering this material. Even searching for your exact question title on Google gives several positive results with the same info.

Comment: Yeah, I tried those other methods as well. They didn't use the 'gsub' method at least. I saw `as.Date(d,'%m/%d/%y')` which still didn't give me the result I wanted. In fact, I was getting these values like "0001-01-20" "0001-02-20" "0001-03-20" "0001-04-20" "0001-05-20" which didn't make any sense.

Comment: `Browse[2]> head(dates1)
[1] "0001-01-20" "0001-02-20" "0001-03-20" "0001-04-20" "0001-05-20" "0001-06-20"`


`Browse[2]> okay1 <- as.Date(dates1, format="%m/%d/%y")`


`Browse[2]> head(okay1)
[1] "0001-01-20" "0001-02-20" "0001-03-20"
[4] "0001-04-20" "0001-05-20" "0001-06-20"`

So even with googling I was still getting something strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input date is in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you can call `as.Date()` on it directly to get a Date-classed object, and then `format()` can be used to stringify it in any format specifiable using the format specifiers documented [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

```
d <- '2008-01-01';
format(as.Date(d),'%m/%d/%Y');
## [1] "01/01/2008"
```

If you really don't want those leading zeroes, you'll have to strip them off yourself using `gsub()`:

```
gsub('\\b0+','',format(as.Date(d),'%m/%d/%Y'));
## [1] "1/1/2008"
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that `2008-01-01` is a string, and that you want `1/1/2008` to also be a string.

You can do this using `format()`, but there's likely a better solution. And if you really want no zeros in your output (as opposed to `01/01/2008`) then I do not think `format()` will help you.

```
Date = "2008-01-01" 
format(as.Date(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for to convert an m/d/Y date to Y-m-d